# How to make Text scroll down automatically whenever text overcomes the visual area?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, scroll, tkinter

Let's say I have a text widget called `self.txt`. I also have a scrollbar, called `scroll`.

I have configured the scrollbar to work with `self.txt`, but I need the `Text` widget to stay scrolled down, whenever text gets added to it.

Is this doable?

Comment: Can you be a little clearer and use paragraphs? It would be easier for me to read and the others after me who would like to answer your question.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac I'll TLDR it for you: I have a text widget, and every few seconds a line of text gets inserted. When the text widget is full of text, it will stay in this position but insert text under my current text, so I have to scroll down. I want it to automatically scroll down, but things like `self.txt.bind("<<Modified>>", self.main)` stop working after one time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this should work: every time the text is modified, this should be called:

```
def modified(self, event):
    self.txt.see(END)  # tkinter.END if you use namespaces
```

To catch the modification, use:

```
self.txt.bind('<<Modified>>', self.modified)
```

Comment: thanks, but somehow this doesn't work for me. I changed the `self.txt.see` to `self.txt.insert`, to see what happened, and it will only insert something in the first line, after which, it will stop inserting. TLDR: Will only `see` one line, but that one line is already visible on the moment it gets inserted into my `self.txt`.

Comment: Fixed it, added the `self.txt.see(END)` to the function that actually inserts the text into the widget, so it will `see` the `end` every time a new line gets inserted. Not precisely your answer, but will accept it anyway.

Comment: OK, thanks, I changed from 'end' to END. I always use namespaces and the builtin tkinter constants.. so I guess that was one part of the problem. Anyway, you got the point, the key was the `see()` method of text widgets.

Comment: This seems to stop working whenever the `state` of the `Text` widget becomes `DISABLED`...